# How do I search through scope variables in Google Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I set a breakpoint in a javascript function with Google Chrome Developer Tools.

I am looking for a variable in the scope variables of the function with the value "Fred." How do I search for this value amongst the variables within the scope of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've set a breakpoint within Chrome DevTools on a particular line, that's within the scope/context of said variable. When browser execution reaches the breakpoint, you'll have access to all variable/functions within its, and the global, scope.

Navigate to the console tab and start typing, the console will autocomplete variables within scope.

For more information about Chrome DevTools visit:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Thanks, I did set a breakpoint within the function and thus have access to the scope of the variable. How do I now search for that variable with the value "Fred"? This function has 100 local variables.

Comment: hover over each of the variables, this will show a popup with the value it is assigned.

Comment: Actually you can access them from Eclipse debugger if you have recent version of Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/Release_0_3_6#Function_Scope_and_Primitve_Values
Chrome in-browser dev-tools should soon catch up with this feature.

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to add a script to the console so that you can actually perform a search, as the Developer Tools don't allow for this by default.  Here's that function for you (**See my Gist comment below for an update**):

```js
function scanScope(whatToScan, scanValue) {
 for (var key in whatToScan) {
  if (whatToScan[key] == scanValue) {
   console.log(key + ' = ' + whatToScan[key]);   
  } else {
   if( (typeof whatToScan[key] === "object") && (key !== null) ) { 
    scanScope(whatToScan[key], scanValue);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Copy and paste that into the console, and then call it with the scope you want to search through and the value you want to search for.  **Be careful that you don't search too large an object, of course.**  If you're programming in Angular, for instance, and following the "always have a dot" rule, you can scan through it with a call like:

```js
scanScope($scope.model, 'Fred');
```

Comment: Incidentally I've made an enhanced version of this script (since I like and use it often, myself) and posted it as a gist: https://gist.github.com/DorkForce/34eb9a1ebf14cc5b0ba7

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: Hi Abdullah - Is $scope defined before you ran scanScope?  If you can, please provide the commands you entered that led up to this error.  Thanks-

Answer (score -2):

manually in console this way:

```
console.log(this);
```

OR

```
console.log({set x(){}});
```

which is equivalent to:

```
console.log(Object.defineProperty({},'x',{get: function(){}}));
```

in console look up:

`get x: function (){}` --> `<function scope>` --> `Global: Window`