# Programmatically accessing function scope using Chrome DevTools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scope, google-chrome-devtools

When I open up Chrome (v35) DevTools and inspect an object, the console can show me things nested within functions, including something labeled as the '"function scope".

For example, when looking at stackoverflow.com, I can see that there's a global `$` object containing another function called `Callbacks`. `Callbacks`, as does `$`, has a functional scope containing `Closure` and `Global`.

[image: screenshot of Chrome DevTools console]

- *Question 1:* What is the difference between some named object nested directly within a function and some object contained within a Closure in its function scope?
- *Question 2:* How do I programmatically reference a function scope in the console? `window.$.Callbacks.???`? `chrome.function???(window.$.Callbacks)`

The reason I ask is because I'm looking for memory leaks and would like to search the objects held within functions' closures based on object types and property names.

Comment: Is setting a breakpoint an option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969062/tool-to-track-down-javascript-memory-leak/12061206#12061206

Comment: Both setting breakpoints and using heap snapshots requires me to interact with the DevTools GUI. I'm looking to programmatically search through the information displayed in DevTools. For the app I'm working on, there are far too many objects for me to want to manually sift through heap deltas or click-and-expand through stacks.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between some named object nested directly within a function and some object contained within a Closure in its function scope?

The object nested directly with the function is a property of the function object. For example, `$.Callback` has a `.length` property with value `1`, it does have a `.prototype` property, it does inherit (`__proto__`) from `Function.prototype` etc.

The object in the scope is a variable that is accessible from the scope that surrounds the function. See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572)

> How do I programmatically reference a function scope in the console?

You cannot. Scopes are not programatically accessible. I don't think the devtools have any helpers to allow this either. See also [How do I search through scope variables in Google Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11438549/1048572)

Comment: Is there a way to export Chrome's `console.dir` output tree (outside of screenshot + OCR) to a text file?

Comment: I don't know of any. Theoretically you should be able to fork the open-source debugger an add such a functionality…