# How to see JS scope chain's variable object in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there way to see the scope chain objects in chrome devtools or in any browser.

For the below code I can only find the global variable and also for nested functions as well, I am only seeing the global variable. Can anyone help with this. Please guide me if I am not in the right direction.

E.g.

```
var global = "Global var";
function f1() {
    var local = "Local var";
};
```

[image: Screenshot from google chrome devtools]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11438549/1048572?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure scope of that function *is* the global scope.

If you want to see the local scope of that function, you need to call it:

```
var global = "Global var";
function f1() {
    var local = "Local var";
    debugger;
};
f1();
```

Then use the [scope view](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#paused-breakpoint) of your debugger.