# Why can't I call this js function from the dev console in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

WebPage that I research uses JS for doing some stuff. In the JS source code of the webpage I found this

```
i.audioUnmaskSource(e.src)
```

When I am trying to call this function from the console in Chrome it says

```
VM1452:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Also Scope in developer tools says that `i` is an Object and is inside the Closure.
How can I access this function from Console in Chrome?
[Scope of devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A70V.png)

Here is the part of code that is called. It is a function `audioUnamskSource` as you can see:

```
function r(e) {
    if (!a() && ~e.indexOf("audio_api_unavailable")) {
        var t = e.split("?extra=")[1].split("#")
          , n = "" === t[1] ? "" : o(t[1]);
        if (t = o(t[0]),
        "string" != typeof n || !t)
            return e;
        n = n ? n.split(String.fromCharCode(9)) : [];
        for (var r, s, l = n.length; l--; ) {
            if (s = n[l].split(String.fromCharCode(11)),
            r = s.splice(0, 1, t)[0],
            !i[r])
                return e;
            t = i[r].apply(null, s)
        }
        if (t && "http" === t.substr(0, 4))
            return t
    }
    return e
}
```

Comment: If you just enter `i` does it return something?

Comment: Well what is `i`? Pretty hard to help without the right code, but if something is not in global scope than you would not be able to call it. You can set a break point where it is defined and call it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438549/how-do-i-search-through-scope-variables-in-google-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: It's hard to understand which 'i' is it is exactly.Because code is written very strange.The are a lot of different i's.In Crome I can't click on 'i' and see which 'i' is it, like in example in Xcode or VS.I can show what is inside

Comment: added what is inside the function

Comment: The code looks minimized, so `i` is likely scoped. You can't access scoped variables. Look for the code that says `i = ...` (it's probably enclosed in something else) and add `window.i = i;` after it if you want to access `i` from your console. You shouldn't do this in production.

Comment: When you say it is inside of a closure, then I'm assuming a function/object is returned from inside of another function. That returned function/object needs to provide an interface to the function you are trying to call. I cannot see that interface in the code that you have shown.

Comment: Is this code cherry-picked from `audioplayer.js`?  If so, here's the de-minified version: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a83dd7ee6024af69921d678b669ceb4.  I can't make sense of it, perhaps others can help.

Comment: Yes that is 'audioplayer.js'.And I want to call function audioUnmaskSource from the console